# One word for an idea that is somewhat supportive of a hypothesis?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun that is a weaker form of the word 'evidence'. For eg. 'Large fossilized eggs in Australia suggests that there were a few flying dinosaurs living here'. 'The Company's stock prices suggests that something is amiss'. What would be the appropriate noun that describes such a weak certainty?

Comment: **Hints**, maybe

Comment: Is that a noun??

Comment: @user2277550 Do you know how to use a dictionary to identify parts of speech? If so, please look up *hint*, and tell us what you find.  Also consider *evidence*.

Comment: @user2277550 Noun and verb. Google "define hint" and see if that helps you. :)

Comment: @user2277550 do you want a noun? Or what?

Comment: oxymoron is what I would call "a weak certainty".   Do you mean "strong possibility"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Indication** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indication)

> *noun*
> a sign or piece of information that indicates something.
>
> *"The visit was an indication of the improvement in relations between the countries."*

Comment: Hello, Rome. See the reference I have added for you? You should add such details next time. :)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hint)

> *noun* a slight indication of the existence, approach, or nature of something
> *"They'll betray you at the first hint of trouble"*
>
> <sub>*synonyms: clue, cue, indication, inkling, intimation, lead, suggestion*</sub>

Answer (score 6):

***[Suggestion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/suggestion)***

> 2. Something that implies or indicates a certain fact or situation

***[Implication](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/implication)***

> 1. The conclusion that can be drawn from something although it is not explicitly stated

Answer (score 1):

I consider the background of your question to be the following:

1. Let *P* be a proposition.
2. Let *x* be an observation.

Then if *x* confirms *P*, we call *x* evidence for *P*. What you're after is a word for *x* if it only supports *P* or is just weak evidence for *P*.

In that case, you can call *x* a **positive instance** or a **confirmatory instance** in support of *P*.

> **Positive** *adjective*
> 1.1 Expressing or implying affirmation, agreement, or permission
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/positive)
>
> **Confirmatory** *adjective, from the verb **confirm***
> 1 Establish the truth or correctness of (something previously believed or suspected to be the case)
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confirm?q=confirmatory#confirm__17)
>
> **Instance** *noun*
> 1 An example or single occurrence of something
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/instance)

Consider the [Raven paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox), where each black raven constitutes a piece of evidence in support of the statement that *all ravens are black*, but each non-black non-raven (e.g. a white table) is also a piece of supportive evidence for the same statement. A yellow raven would disprove the statement.

Each black raven and each white table, then, can be called a *positive* or *confirmatory instance* in support of the statement that *all ravens are black*. Each such instance on its own is insufficient to establish the statement, hence the notion that they are *weak* pieces of evidence, as you require.

Comment: How is the fact that the ocean is deep supportive evidence for the statement that all puddles are shallow?

Comment: @TimRomano The link lists several approaches to resolving this paradox. Basically, if one asserts that all X have the property Y, then any X with property (not Y) defeats the assertion. So if property (not Y) is observed, but it's observed on something other than X, the assertion is still in play. This is akin to the adage commonly attributed to the fictional Sherlock Holmes: *Eliminate all other factors, and the one which remains must be the truth.* Each non-X that is also non-Y is in theory one such elimination. In practice, there are often too many to eliminate for this method to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

One not mentioned thus far: "conducive" - that is, the evidence does not present problems for the hypothesis, and in fact fits in with the claims made, without directly supporting or providing evidence of a causal nature.

Ethan suspected carpenter ants, not termites, were to blame for the destruction of his porch. The numerous carpenter ants he noticed walking around on the ground nearby were conducive to this line of thinking, but Ethan was a particular sort of erstwhile myrmecologist. Nothing short of the nest itself would convince him. Until then, something slowly converted his porch to sawdust.